# Aruco marker pose estimation on curved surface

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I assume the pose estimate from aruco markers is only valid when they are affixed to a flat surface.  What about attaching them to a slightly curved surface?  Is there any way to correct for the surface curvature in the resulting pose?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to get the pose estimate for a curved surface using an Aruco board, though it may be physically difficult to construct and measure. Aruco boards do not need to be planar; they can describe any arrangement of markers in 3D space. So the following steps should work:

- attach markers to your curved surface (which may be a challenge if the surface is not developable).
- calculate, or directly measure, the 3D positions of the physical markers' corners in your preferred Cartesian coordinate system.
- define an Aruco board using the markers' 3D corner positions and IDs.
- tune the Aruco detection parameters (at least adaptive threshold and polygonal approximation) to give robust marker detection in the presence of curvature in the marker edges and localised lighting variations due to the curved surface.
- once marker detection is reliable, use estimatePoseBoard() to get the pose estimate of the board, and hence the curved surface, in the same Cartesian coordinate system. estimatePoseBoard() finds a best-fit solution for the pose while considering all visible markers simultaneously.

Note: I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: How about a bend/fold?

Comment: A bend/fold will work just fine, as long as the markers themselves are not bent to the point where they become undetectable.  Easy way to avoid this, put markers either side of the fold, not on it.